# For $(l^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$ and $e_n=(0,0,.,1,0,.)$ and a bounded linear functional $\Phi$ find $p\geq 1$ where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^p$ converges?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

For $(l^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$ and $e_n=(0,0,...,1,0,...)$ and a bounded linear functional $\Phi$ find a value of $p\geq 1$ where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^p$ converges for $b_n=\Phi(e_n)$?

Ok so since $\Phi$ is bounded I know $|\Phi(e_n)|\leq C\|e_n\|_2 = C$
so:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^p=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\Phi(e_n)|^p \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |C|^p$$

but what does this prove? Or have I made a mistake?

Comment: If $\sum |b_n|^p$ converges, then $|b_n| \to 0$. Can you demonstrate that for a bounded linear functional, $\Phi$, that the sequence $|\Phi(e_n)| \to 0$ ?

Comment: Of course, this is just a necessary condition.

Comment: I don't believe you can can you? Surely $|\Phi(e_n)| \leq C$ for all $n\geq 1$?

Comment: Certainly it is bounded by the norm of the operator. However, if $\sum |b_n|^p$ converges for any $p$, then  $|b_n| \to 0$.

Comment: I missed the adjective "functional". This doesn't hold for general operators, however, the Reisz representation theorem would be the way to go as in Davide's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$p=2$ does the job. To see this, represent the bounded linear form $\Phi$ as $\Phi(x)=\langle x_0,x \rangle$. Bessel's equality gives the wanted convergence. Indeed, we have 
$$\sum_{n=1} ^\infty|\langle x_0,e_n\rangle|^2=\lVert x_0\rVert^2  $$
and $\langle x_0,e_n\rangle =\Phi(e_n)$.
In general, we cannot hope for a better $p$, that is, $p\lt 2$. Indeed, take $1/2\lt\alpha\leqslant 1/p$ and $x_0:=\sum_n n^{-\alpha}e_n$.

Comment: How does this tie in with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^p$ converging?

Comment: @Daniel See edit.